# How to create new column replacing multiple values in a column

Tags: python

I have position_df having job titles with lot of inconsistent entries. For example instead of Accountant there are these instances:

```
lst = ['Aaccountant', 
         'Accountantsnt',
         'Accountantant',
         'Acauntant',
         'Acccount',
         'Acccountant', 
         'Accontant',
         'Accosiate',
         'Accounant',
         'Accounet', 
         'Accountamt',
         'Accountan',
         'Accountanat',
         'Accountans', 
         'Accountat',
         'Accountat',
         'Accountc',
         'Accountend',
         'Accountent',
         'Accounter', 
         'Accountnat', 
         'Accountrepresentative', 
         'AccountsAdministrator',
         'Accoutant',
         'ACCOUTING',
         'ACCOUTN',
         'Accts',
         'Accuontant', 
         'Acontent',
         'Acoount',
         'Acoount',
         'Acount',
         'Acountant',
         'Acountante',
         'Acountsnt',
         'Accountantante',
         'Accountantsnt']
```

I tried the following code:

```
import re
pat = r"\b(?:{})\b".format('|'.join(lst))
position_df['position_cleaned'] = position_df['position'].replace(pat, 'Accountant', regex=True)
position_df.position_cleaned.value_counts()
```

My ouptut is:
Accountant                                          27

The code looks fine until this step, but on repeating the process for other spelling mistakes, I do not get the desired output.

```
del lst, pat
lst = [ 'Adiministrative',
 'Adimn',
 'Admenstretiv',
 'Admenstritive',
 'Admi']
pat = r"\b(?:{})\b".format('|'.join(lst))
position_df['position_cleaned'] = position_df['position'].replace(pat, 'Administrator', regex=True)
```

What could be wrong with my approach.
I am new to python, thanks inn advance!

Comment: why are you doing `position_df.position.value_counts()` and not `position_df.position_cleaned.value_counts()`? don't you want to count position after cleaning it with regex?

Comment: I am sorry for the typo. I am doing the ```position_df.position_cleaned.value_counts()```  only. The results are not satisfactory with my approach, I need a scalable solution for whatever type of spelling mistakes we encounter in future.

Comment: How do you know the code doesn't wokr? what is the output of the administrator output?

Comment: One idea I can think is, if you know all valid answers, in case there is a mistake that is not in your mistake_list is to compare the undefined word with all possible valid answer and the word with more letters in common is probably the right one. Otherwise you can try an grammar check api. In any case I think your solution is valid as a first attempt because it is fast and you only try something else if the word still unknown

Comment: ```from textblob import TextBlob
position_df['position_cleaned'] = position_df['position'].apply(lambda tweet: TextBlob(tweet).correct())``` Getting result like 3D ARTEST (O, f, , A, R, T, E, S, T). I want the result as Artist

Comment: ```from textblob import TextBlob
position_df['position_cleaned'] = position_df['position'].apply(lambda tweet: str(TextBlob(tweet).correct()))``` This helps but not very reliable. For example vp gets corrected as 'up'. I need Vice President there

Answer (score 0):

See the code snippet below that I use before.

```
class Correctness:
    """Returns the most similar word from given input"""

    def __init__(self, vocabulary, length_limit=1, char_limit=2):
        self._vocabulary = []
        self.vocabulary = vocabulary
        self._length_limit = length_limit
        self._char_limit = char_limit

    @property
    def vocabulary(self):
        """returns the vocabulary dictionary"""
        return self._vocabulary

    @vocabulary.setter
    def vocabulary(self, value):
        """adds the given input into vocabulary dictionary"""
        if isinstance(value, str):
            self._vocabulary.append(value)
        elif isinstance(value, (list, tuple, dict, set)):
            self._vocabulary.extend(list(value))
        else:
            raise ValueError(
                "type {!r} is not supported".format(
                    value.__class__.__name__
                )
            )

    def add_vocabulary(self, value):
        """adds the given input into vocabulary dictionary"""
        self.vocabulary = value

    def remove_vocabulary(self, value, ignore_errors=True):
        "removes the given word from vocabulary dictionary"
        try:
            self._vocabulary.pop(self._vocabulary.index(value))
        except ValueError:
            if not ignore_errors:
                raise

    def remove_vocabularies(self, values, ignore_errors=True):
        """removes the given words from vocabulary dictionary"""
        for value in values:
            self.remove_vocabulary(value, ignore_errors=ignore_errors)

    def _filter_by_length(self, length):
        if self._length_limit is None:
            yield from self.vocabulary
            return

        for choise in self.vocabulary:
            if length-self._length_limit <= len(choise) <= length+self._length_limit:
                yield choise

    def _filter_by_char(self, text, choises):
        for choise in choises:
            similar_chars = set()
            for char in text:
                if char in choise:
                    similar_chars.add(char)
            similarity = len(similar_chars)
            if len(set(text)) - similarity < self._char_limit:
                yield choise, similarity / len(text)

    def spell_check(self, text):
        """finds the most similar word"""
        if text in self.vocabulary:
            return text

        possibles = self._filter_by_length(len(text))
        possibles = self._filter_by_char(text, possibles)
        max_rate = 0
        most_simiar = None
        for possible, rate in possibles:
            if rate > max_rate:
                max_rate = rate
                most_simiar = possible

        return most_simiar
```

The `spell_check` function returns the most similar word if matches to the threshold, None otherwise.

```
jobs = [
 'Aaccountant', 'Accountantsnt', 'Accountantant', 'Acauntant', 'Acccount',
 'Acccountant', 'Accontant', 'Accosiate', 'Accounant', 'Accounet', 'Accountamt',
 'Accountan', 'Accountanat', 'Accountans', 'Accountat', 'Accountat', 'Accountc',
 'Accountend', 'Accountent', 'Accounter', 'Accountnat', 'Accountrepresentative',
 'AccountsAdministrator', 'Accoutant', 'ACCOUTING', 'ACCOUTN', 'Accts', 'Accuontant',
 'Acontent', 'Acoount', 'Acoount', 'Acount', 'Acountant', 'Acountante', 'Acountsnt',
 'Accountantante', 'Accountantsnt'
]

correctness = Correctness(vocabulary=["Accountant"], length_limit=None, char_limit=7)
print("{0:25}         {1}\n".format("Original", "Converted"))
for job in jobs:
    print("{0:25} ->      {1}".format(job, correctness.spell_check(job.lower())))
```

I disabled the length limit and set the char limit to 7.

The length limit filters by length(+/- threshold).
The char limit filters by the set of chars in the word.

The output is:

```
Original                          Converted

Aaccountant               ->      Accountant
Accountantsnt             ->      Accountant
Accountantant             ->      Accountant
Acauntant                 ->      Accountant
Acccount                  ->      Accountant
Acccountant               ->      Accountant
Accontant                 ->      Accountant
Accosiate                 ->      Accountant
Accounant                 ->      Accountant
Accounet                  ->      Accountant
Accountamt                ->      Accountant
Accountan                 ->      Accountant
Accountanat               ->      Accountant
Accountans                ->      Accountant
Accountat                 ->      Accountant
Accountat                 ->      Accountant
Accountc                  ->      Accountant
Accountend                ->      Accountant
Accountent                ->      Accountant
Accounter                 ->      Accountant
Accountnat                ->      Accountant
Accountrepresentative     ->      Accountant
AccountsAdministrator     ->      Accountant
Accoutant                 ->      Accountant
ACCOUTING                 ->      Accountant
ACCOUTN                   ->      Accountant
Accts                     ->      Accountant
Accuontant                ->      Accountant
Acontent                  ->      Accountant
Acoount                   ->      Accountant
Acoount                   ->      Accountant
Acount                    ->      Accountant
Acountant                 ->      Accountant
Acountante                ->      Accountant
Acountsnt                 ->      Accountant
Accountantante            ->      Accountant
Accountantsnt             ->      Accountant
```

If you set the `char_limit` to 3:

```
Original                          Converted

Aaccountant               ->      Accountant
Accountantsnt             ->      Accountant
Accountantant             ->      Accountant
Acauntant                 ->      Accountant
Acccount                  ->      Accountant
Acccountant               ->      Accountant
Accontant                 ->      Accountant
Accosiate                 ->      None
Accounant                 ->      Accountant
Accounet                  ->      Accountant
Accountamt                ->      Accountant
Accountan                 ->      Accountant
Accountanat               ->      Accountant
Accountans                ->      Accountant
Accountat                 ->      Accountant
Accountat                 ->      Accountant
Accountc                  ->      Accountant
Accountend                ->      Accountant
Accountent                ->      Accountant
Accounter                 ->      Accountant
Accountnat                ->      Accountant
Accountrepresentative     ->      None
AccountsAdministrator     ->      None
Accoutant                 ->      Accountant
ACCOUTING                 ->      Accountant
ACCOUTN                   ->      Accountant
Accts                     ->      Accountant
Accuontant                ->      Accountant
Acontent                  ->      Accountant
Acoount                   ->      Accountant
Acoount                   ->      Accountant
Acount                    ->      Accountant
Acountant                 ->      Accountant
Acountante                ->      Accountant
Acountsnt                 ->      Accountant
Accountantante            ->      Accountant
Accountantsnt             ->      Accountant
```

As you can see, some of the converted values are `None`. You can change the algorithm or the threshold values to get the desire output.